# Origin [domain] not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. ASP .net CORE API mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Trying to call an asp .net CORE webAPI from an asp net core mvc website, I always get :

> Origin [domain] not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Main site url like : `https://mysite/Login/API_Request`
Api url like : `https://auth.mysite/api/values`

Api work well when I enter the url directly but ajax request not working :

**Request :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
getIdentity();
});

function getIdentity() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: "",
    url: "https://auth.mysite/api/values",
    dataType: 'json',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (response) {
        response = response.replace(/\"/g, "");
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.log(response.statusText);
    }
});
}
```

**API Controller**

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[EnableCors("AllowAll")]
  public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get()
    {
        var u = User;

        WindowsIdentity identity = null;

        if (HttpContext== null)
        {
            identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        }
        else
        {
            identity = HttpContext.User.Identity as WindowsIdentity;
        }
        return Json(identity.User.Value);
    }
}
```

I've try with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors but I didn't manage to make it working :

**startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options => {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials();
                    });
            });
         ...
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseCors("AllowAll");


            app.UseMvc();

        }
```

Comment: I see, my question is stupid, but anyway: have you configured Cors in startup.cs for API, not the web site? And the other: do you really need credentials in the request? The CORS specification states that setting origins to "*" (all origins) is invalid if the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header is present.

Comment: @d_f The request code is on the main site but the APIController and startup.cs are on the API. Credential seems indeed necessary, I thinks it's because the API use Windows authentication. I've just republish the main site and the API and now it's seems to work jsut fine with the same code as above.

Answer (score 0):

The code above seems to work, I just publish the API and main site again and it's just work fine. AllowCredentials seems required, I think it's because the API use Windows Authentication but the main site don't. I've change a little bit the authorization on the API statup :

```
services.AddCors(options => {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
                    builder =>
                    {
                      builder.WithOrigins("http://mysite").WithMethods("GET").AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials();
                    });
            });
```

for some security reasons.